# Null pointer exception in gui of jmeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, jmeter

[Please click here for the jmeter test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNUwx.png)

[Please click here for the jmeter log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3rEH.png) I am trying to hit the server by JUnit Request using Jmeter, but i am getting the followig error:

> jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException.

Here is my log file

2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui 
2015/12/04 12:53:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui 
2015/12/04 12:53:18 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool' 
2015/12/04 12:53:18 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file C:\Users\Vishal\Downloads\apache-jmeter-2.13 (1)\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2015/12/04 12:53:19 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2015/12/04 12:53:19 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2015/12/04 12:53:19 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2015/12/04 12:53:19 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2015/12/04 12:53:28 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:272)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:45)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/12/04 12:53:28 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:272)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.addFileMenu(MenuFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.addFileMenu(MenuFactory.java:200)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.getDefaultSamplerMenu(MenuFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.gui.AbstractSamplerGui.createPopupMenu(AbstractSamplerGui.java:49)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/12/04 12:53:31 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:272)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.addFileMenu(MenuFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.addFileMenu(MenuFactory.java:200)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.getDefaultSamplerMenu(MenuFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.gui.AbstractSamplerGui.createPopupMenu(AbstractSamplerGui.java:49)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.displayPopUp(JMeterTreeListener.java:244)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.mousePressed(JMeterTreeListener.java:193)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/12/04 12:53:32 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:416)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:73)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/12/04 12:53:37 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:272)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:45)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/12/04 12:53:37 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:272)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.addFileMenu(MenuFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.addFileMenu(MenuFactory.java:200)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.getDefaultSamplerMenu(MenuFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.gui.AbstractSamplerGui.createPopupMenu(AbstractSamplerGui.java:49)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/12/04 12:53:40 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:416)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:73)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Listeners will be started after enabling running version 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties) 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='C:\Users\Vishal\Downloads\apache-jmeter-2.13 (1)\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin' 
2015/12/04 12:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2015/12/04 12:53:42 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getTestElementCheckSum(GuiPackage.java:853)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:435)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:416)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:73)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you show jmeter.log ?and your test plan and how you run jmeter ? which version ...

Comment: Have added in the question

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK any help?

Comment: I would need the jmeter.log as text file and the content as text of lib, lib/ext, bin. Your installation seems to be corrupt. What java version are you using ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK, i have added the log file in my question, the java version which i am using is "1.8.0_65"

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK my log file as well as my libraries are here: http://shrib.com/OL246aOUO6Z9qze?v=nc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're experiencing clash between Selenium and JMeter dependencies jars. Solution would be:

1. Install clean latest version of JMeter
2. Install [WebDriver Sampler Plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)
3. Inspect /lib folder of your JMeter installation, locate duplicate .jar files which names start from http* and delete older versions
4. Restart JMeter and you're done.

You can also run your .jmx file via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool - it will automatically download and configure the latest JMeter with Plugins. You'll be able to find "good" installation under .bzt/jmeter-taurus folder in your home directory

Comment: @Dmirti T, When i use Firefox driver it works, but i am not able to run it when i use HTML Unit Driver. I get the following error in the log file: com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.sslcontext

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T could you please help me on this question, really need some help, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690957/jmeter-distributed-testing-using-java-code/36695479?noredirect=1#comment61016476_36695479
Thank you