# Jmeter Distributed Testing using Java Code

Tags: java, jmeter, distributed

i am able to run Jmeter using Java Code, but if i want to do the same as Distributed Testing then how do i add the remote engines in the Java Code.

Comment: @Dmitri T : Can you please help me with the same. Thank you

Comment: @Dmitri any clue about this? would really be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [sample](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/jakarta-jmeter-2.0.1/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/gui/action/RemoteStart.java.shtml) code to start a remote engine from Java code.
[Documentation about remote testing with JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
And a [sample](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/57cef9e2b1c952f669417163b4f0c4a679353719/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/demo/JMeterFromScratch.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) to code a local test.

Comment: There is no mention of Distributed using Java Code, there is only Distribution Testing using command line where i have to use "-R". I want to know how can i do run jmeter on remote engines using Java Code

Comment: You'll have to create remote servers (either using the GUI or Java) and start each one. The links I provided you shows how to create each one.

Comment: I have created my servers, need to know how to run the tests on those servers through JAVA code

Comment: Thanx for that, but how do i integrate the remote code with my Local Test code? is there any better way to add the remote hosts in the local test code?

Comment: You can create a configuration file to set all remote servers.

Comment: can you please help me out with that. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @Augusto, would be really great if you could help out i  this, still unable to do anything. How do i integrate the Remote Server Code to the Local test one?

Comment: I don't understand what you didn't get... The first link I've sent shows exactly how to start a remote JMeter engine. If you want to make the configuration dinamic you can store in some kind of database like SQLite. Here's a [sample](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm) how to use it.

Comment: Hi Augusto, Thank you for the reply, i want to know how to integrate the sample code for Remote engines with the sample code for the local test. I want to start the remote engines using the Java Code for which the sample code i have understood, but how do i integrate the same with my local test one.

Comment: you don't need to write any code for the local test. check out the documentation in the link of my answer and check the steps 0 and 1 for setting up the servers of your tests. you can see there how to configure everything. then you just have to execute your remote server code

Comment: Hi @augusto, thanx a lot for the help, have a small doubt, say i have 3 servers, Server 1(Jmeter Master), Server2(Jmeter Slave) and Server3(Jmeter Slave),when i do distributed testing for my maven-jmeter API Project, do i have to have the instance of the code instance or anything on the slaves?

Comment: @VishalPuliani I didn't understand your question very well. Are you asking if the test code has to be on slaves or on server?

Comment: yes i want to know if the code has to be there on the slaves as well, or only on the master & how do i trigger the test to run on the slave from the master

Comment: @VishalPuliani check the method doRemoteStart in the first link I've posted. And yes the test should be in the slaves too.

Comment: Augusto, i am sorry for troubling so much, but i am not able to execute it, i want to explain it clearly, so can we have a personal chat somewhere?

Comment: hi @Aususto, i am able to connect the master to the slaves from the code, but how do i run my _TestPlan_ on the slaves?